# Image uploaded works in localhost but not on server (s3)

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Well, I have an option in the system where I can see some documents sent by the user. But the images appear as broken icons.
As "localhost" everything works great, but I can't see the images when I run straight from the website. (On the s3 everything is working normally, I can see the images.)
In the brownser console, an error is thrown about the route that the request is being made "api.mysite.com/the-image-example.png" with status code 404.
What I don't understand is **why the request is being made there and not directly on amazon s3** (there I have the images loading normally). Someone cal help me with that??

How images appear: [image]

This is the code
Upload config:

```
const tmpFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'tmp');

export const mimeTypesPhotos = [
  'image/png',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/bmp',
  'image/webp',
];

export const mimeTypesVideos = ['video/webm', 'video/ogg', 'video/mp4'];

export const mimeTypesPng = ['application/pdf'];

const pngRoutes = ['/requests/test', '/test/:id/confirm'];

interface IUploadConfig {
  driver: 's3' | 'disk';

  tmpFolder: string;
  uploadsFolder: string;

  multer: multer.Options;

  image: {
    height: number;
    width: number;
  };

  config: {
    disk: unknown;
    aws: {
      bucket: string;
    };
  };
}

export default {
  driver: process.env.STORAGE_DRIVER,

  tmpFolder,
  uploadsFolder: path.resolve(tmpFolder, 'uploads'),

  multer: {
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: tmpFolder,
      filename: (request, file, callback) => {
        const fileHash = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
        const fileName = `${fileHash}-${file.originalname}`;

        return callback(null, fileName);
      },
    }),
    fileFilter: (request, file, callback) => {
      const url = matchId(request.originalUrl);

      const mimetypes = [...mimeTypesPhotos];

      if (pngRoutes.includes(url)) {
        mimetypes.push(...mimeTypesPng);
      }

      if (!mimetypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        return callback(new Error("File doesn't supported"));
      }
      return callback(null, true);
    },
  },

  image: {
    width: Number(process.env.MAX_IMAGE_SIZE || '1024'),
    height: Number(process.env.MAX_IMAGE_SIZE || '1024'),
  },

  config: {
    disk: {},
    aws: {
      bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET || 'mybucket',
    },
  },
} as IUploadConfig;
```

Router file (where is calling the route i mean):

```
app.use('/files', express.static(uploadConfig.uploadsFolder));
```

The Media Entity:

```
 @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  type: 'photo';

  @Column()
  media: string;

  @Expose({ name: 'mediaUrl' })
  getMediaUrl(): string | null {
    if (!this.media) {
      return null;
    }

    switch (uploadConfig.driver) {
      case 'disk':
        return `${process.env.APP_API_URL}/files/${this.media}`;
      case 's3':
        return `https://${uploadConfig.config.aws.bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${this.media}`;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The code you shared is related to how the images are uploaded but your question is about how the images are viewed in your app.  Have you verified the files are in S3 as you expect?  If so, you should update this question to provide the UI code trying to load the image.

Comment: @Corin Yes, on the s3 everything is working normally, I can see the images. I updated my question. Can you help me?

Comment: Alright, so the problem is viewing the images.  The code you have provided here is not related to the problem.  Can you provide the code that links to those images?  It sounds as though the problem is with how the files are referenced.

Comment: Ok :) I add more where else is related to this. I only see this on the code.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the process.env.STORAGE_DRIVER.  Just to prove that's the case, I'd add a console.log just before the switch in the Media Entity to verify the configuration is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1

we need to Enable CORS in the API gateway, so  click on the resource and then click on the Action button and Enable CORS. In CORS settings the value of Access-Control-Allow-Headers is '*' and Access-Control-Allow-Origin is '*' , and leave other settings as it is. Click on Enable CORS and replace existing CORS headers.

Step-2
Now, go to the settings of that API on which you are working. In settings enable Binary Media Types. Set the value of that field like this */* , and Save the changes.